# table-cell spacing

Tags: css

I want to be able to put spacing bettween the center of the 2 p tags. I also wanted them to act like a table cell

**HTML**

```
        <div class="spent">
          <p>Total spending monthly</p>
          <p>$200</p>
        </div>
```

**CSS**

```
   .spent p {
      display: table-cell;
       padding: 10px 0px 0 10px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind I just needed to set a width on the first p tag. Here is an example in case it helps someone
Example:

```
.spent p:first-child{
   width:200px
}
```